# T-SQL Can't see tables in Object Explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to find some tables with a given column. As I didn't create these tables and need to find which tables I need to reference in my script.

I use this query -

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name like '%someColumn%'
```

From this I can see, `TABLE_CATALOG`, `TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TABLE_NAME`

Let's say:

```
TABLE_CATALOG = MYCAT
TABLE_SCHEMA  = dbo
TABLE_NAME    = myTable
```

I go to the object explorer and expand the tables of catalog `MYCAT` to scroll through the tables, but I can't find `myTable` listed in there. However, if I want, I can query `myTable` for data.

What is the reason why I might not be seeing these tables? Where could I find them?

Comment: Are you pointing to the right Database when running the query on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`?

Comment: @Abhinav I wasn't but now I tried `MYCAT.INFORMATION_SCHEMA` yielded the same results

Comment: @Adjit how do you know that your table exists?

Comment: @JosephStyons because I can query it and get rows from those tables. The `intellisense` typing also pops up the name of the table as I am typing. Unless this can be something other than a table.

Comment: @Adjit Are you sure it's not a `VIEW`?

Comment: @Siyual how can I check against that? Fairly new to this.

Comment: Instead of expanding tables, look at views. It should be right below tables.

Comment: Ahhh, that'll do it. So what's the difference between a `TABLE` and a `VIEW`?

Comment: As a side note, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` returns Views too if a column is found in one.

Comment: Read the following https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @Adjit A `TABLE` is the physical location of the data.  A `VIEW` is a custom, user-defined, way of both viewing the data and controlling access.

Comment: @Siyual So would a `VIEW` pull information from a table, or are they independent of each other?

Comment: `VIEW` is built using tables. Summarily, it is a sql-query stored in Database.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help guys. If someone wants to post an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: @Adjit A `VIEW` would pull information from a `TABLE` - You can right-click on the `VIEW` that you have and select `Script View As` > `CREATE TO` > `New Query Window` to see how it was defined and where it's pulling data from.

Comment: @Adjit: Were you able to find your table?

Comment: @Abhinav yes, turns out `myTable` was a `VIEW`, now I am doing some more digging per Siyual to find the correlated tables.

Comment: Cool! Then @Siyual got the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  allows you to get information about all columns for all tables and views within a database.

you can verify with this query:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS schema_name 
,o.name AS object_name
,type_desc FROM sys.objects AS o INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON o.object_id = c.object_id WHERE c.name  like '%someColumn%'
```

Another way to find TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME and get the type is :

```
select * ,t.TABLE_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME where column_name like '%someColumn%'
```